# SPFx - WebPart error after upload in SPOffice365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, spfx-webparts

When i upload my web part in app catalog, after install in dev site.
**I have following error:**

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is your gulp server is running? Try to make `https://localhost:4321/ ` as trusted url and that will solve your problem. Otherwise you can upload the scripts to document library and use in client side web part.

Comment: Write it as an answer to approve it

Comment: posted as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your gulp server is running? Try to make https://localhost:4321/ as trusted url (browser options) and that will solve your problem.

Otherwise you can upload the scripts to document library and use in client side web part.

Also note you can use this for development, as you are using resource from your localhost. But when you move to production you need to host the scripts file somewhere accessible to everyone (a document library or CDN). To achieve this you can navigate to solution `config -> write-manifests.json` and upadate `cdnBasePath` property to CDN URL or Document Library URL (till folders in which your scripts are uploaded).

Answer (score 3):

The page is trying to load resources from `localhost`.

[image: read the error]

If you have uploaded to SharePoint-Online this is "wrong".

Comment: I dont think so, for development you can refer to scripts localhost. For production you need to upload them to CDN or Library from where it will be accessible to everyone. It is because of the trust certificate issue. You can add the URL to trusted url in order to solve.

Comment: @ThinkB4Code: But the title was ".. after upload in SPOffice365.." so I assumed this is "online" - also the top of the image suggests "Developer Site" - it does not look like the SP-Workbench..

Comment: By referring to `after upload in SPOffice365`, he means `.sppkg` and not script files, which is clear by seeing the error. Anyways, I guess he got the solution, which is more important as a community. :)